# Natural Movement with Noise

Tags: javascript, p5.js, noise

Im creating an object that randomly moves in a natural way using noise like this (works as intended):

The objects encounter a collision and their trajectory is manipulated, the movement path now changes to straight line (words as intended)

```
thisRabbit.x = _world.width * (noise(thisRabbit.t));
thisRabbit.y = _world.height * (noise(thisRabbit.t+5));
thisRabbit.t += 0.001;
```

The problem is after this movement , i want the object to start moving in a random direction again as it was initially. If i use the same function, the object jumps to the last location before the trajectory was modified.

```
let vx = this.acquiredFood[0] - this.x;
let vy = this.acquiredFood[1] -  this.y;

let f = (this.genes.speed + 10) / Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy);

vx = vx * f;
vy = vy * f;

let newX = this.x + vx;
let newY = this.y + vy;
```

So how do i get the object to move as before, given a starting position

edit: snippet here: https://editor.p5js.org/vince.chinner/sketches/HPFKR8eIw

Comment: Just a note: I think you have a typo here `Math.sqrt(vx-vx+vy*vy)` should probably be `Math.sqrt(vx*vx+vy*vy)` (assumed it's a vector length)

Comment: For the question, it's not really clear which code is used where (loops? functions?) relatively to (supposed) where your rabbit is drawn. We don't see where the movements change, but as a guess I would say that you forgot to assign `thisRabbit.x` and `thisRabbit.y` to the values `newX` and `newY` when the second movement type resumes to the first..

Comment: @Kaddath see edit

Comment: `i want the object to start moving in a random direction again as it was initially.`

When the Rabbit is in "idle" state, you don't want it to move right?, I checked your sketch and it seems to be working as you described, 

It starts walking, when it gets hungry, it moves around randomly to find food, if it finds food, it eats and sits there idle and when it is hungry again, it starts moving again, If this is not the expected behavior, Could you let us know what is?

Comment: You will see that, when it gets hungry again, after it has eaten, it jumps from the position where it was when it initially encountered the food, before continuing on the random path @Kaddath

Comment: I don't understant what represents `thisRabbit.t` and why is it used in the calculation of the movement.. can you precise it? This may be the problem because the value doesn't seem updated from the moment food is found

Comment: Its a seed to the noise function, otherwise it would be completely random, so i guess i need to calculate the seed given current position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you used a factor from 0 to 1 generated with `noise` and an incremented seed to generate the position by multiplying directly the world dimentions. When reaching food, you cannot increment the seed as to be in the exact position where the movement to get your food led you (I found no inverse function for `noise` to get the seed from the return value).

What you need to do instead is use the noise to increment or decrement the coordinates, so that no matter where the seed is, you don't loose your current position.

Here are the different corrections I applied to the code, as there were also syntax errors, I can't really paste the whole stuff here for copyright reasons (you didn't share the whole code here and the sketch belongs to you)

**MAIN CORRECTION:**

- used a var `found` because returning from the `forEach` callback doesn't make you leave the `findFood` function, but the callback one. And the `forEach` loop doesn't stop. Using this var prevents the further `forEach` tests to be made and allows you to return from `findFood` so that no further move is made after seeing food.
- `noise` is now applied to a value of 4 and I subtract 2, so that `x` and `y` now change with a range of -2 to 2 each. Of course, with this method, you need to check against world dimentions or else the rabbit could leave the world. The seed increment has been changed too or else it would vary too slowly (adapt values as you wish)

```
  findFood(){
    var thisRabbit = this, found = false;
    _world.food.forEach(f => {
      if(!found){
        let d = int(dist(f[0], f[1], thisRabbit.x, thisRabbit.y));
        if(d < (thisRabbit.genes.vision / 2)+3){
          thisRabbit.state = "foundFood";
          this.acquiredFood = f;
          found = true;
        }
      }
    });
    if(found){ return; }
    thisRabbit.x += (noise(thisRabbit.t) * 4) - 2;
    if(thisRabbit.x < 0){ thisRabbit.x = 0; }
    if(thisRabbit.x > _world.width){ thisRabbit.x = _world.width; }
    thisRabbit.y += (noise(thisRabbit.t + 5) * 4) - 2;
    if(thisRabbit.y < 0){ thisRabbit.y = 0; }
    if(thisRabbit.y > _world.height){ thisRabbit.y = _world.height; }
    thisRabbit.t += 0.01;
  }
```

**SYNTAX ERRORS:**

lines 23 / 24: assignment should be with a value (`null` or `false`)

```
    this.genes = null;
    this.acquiredFood = null;
```

lines 129 to 133: end you instructions with a `;` instead of a `,`

```
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.foodDensity = foodDensity;
    this.food = [];
    this.rabits = [];
```

line 156 to 160: there should be no space between `rabbit` and `.t`. Additionnally, because the coordinates are not directly linked to `t`, I would prefer to use `random` for starting position:

```
      let x = this.width * random();
      let y = this.height * random();
      let _rabbit = new rabbit(x, y);
      _rabbit.genes = genes;
      _rabbit.t = t;
```

Comment: Thanks, for the syntax corrections. The movement algorithm is much more refined, thank you

Comment: small correction: the check to see that the object doest go beyond the screen vertically should use the height not the width
if(thisRabbit.y > _world.height){ thisRabbit.y = _world.height; }

Comment: @VincentChinner ah yes you're right, I corrected it at a moment but didn't go throught the copy/paste. edited